# Get list to pdf document Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-recyclerview

How I can add recyclerView list to pdf document?
The recyclerView created from user input..

I'm using this code to get the list, but if the recycler view contains two or more items, the list items are on top of each other in the PDF
How I can fix this problem?

```
for (ModelClass item : modelList){ 
    String title = String.valueOf(item.getTitle());
    canvas.drawText(title,70,90,myPaint);
}
```

Comment: Yes, Java @Robert

Comment: You can use the iTextPdf library. If you want to put you text into the pdf. [example here](https://github.com/pawanharariya/Scan-and-Pay/blob/102ade1ecd7b6d35f5e80d6ddfeb1cb6ec90fd17/Scan%20and%20Pay%20-%20Partner%20App/app/src/main/java/com/anvay/noqueuepaydashboard/fragments/HomeFragment.java#L224C7-L224C7) With this you can create table in the pdf and each item as a row

Comment: But it needs license and open source @pawanSinghHararia

Comment: Using iTextPdf is quite often not a option as it requires a licnese as @Hans say and it is usually not required because the built in PDFDocument class can do pretty much everything that iText can do.

Comment: You don't say anything about how you want to "control each item separately in some parts of pdf" in the question, as you mention in a comment, so it is difficult to fully answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to draw the text directly to the PDF's canvas you can use the recycler's viewholder views to layout and measure them which sizes them and positions them and then draw these views to the PDF's canvas.

You also have to handle how many items you can get on a standard pdf paper size before you have to start a new page.

A basic example for how to create a multiple page PDF from a recyclerview is at https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf

Comment: Thank you for your helping, but I want to control each item separatly in some parts of pdf @Andrew

Comment: You can use the same principle of measuring and laying out views to draw to a PDF's canvas but instead of using the views the recycler is using you can use any type of view you want. For Example I quite often just programmatically create a TableView that is very displayed just to measure and lay it out to a PDF to get the exact PDF I want. The key is that measuring and laying out View sizes them and positions them on the PDF canvas so that they don't overlap each other.